# An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/course_form.html]") Java/Spring/Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, orm, thymeleaf, one-to-one

I get error when trying to get access to `th:field="*{id}"`. I have 2 classes: User and Course.
I'm using spring and thymeleaf
 User class:

```
   @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    public class User {
    
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private Integer id;
    
      @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 45)
      private String email;
      @Column(length = 15, nullable = false)
      private String password;
      @Column(length = 45, nullable = false, name = "first_name")
      private String firstName;
      @Column(length = 45, nullable = false, name = "last_name")
      private String lastName;
    
    
      public Integer getId() {
        return id;
      }
    
      public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
      }
    
      public String getEmail() {
        return email;
      }
    
      public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
      }
    
      public String getPassword() {
        return password;
      }
    
      public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
      }
    
      public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
      }
    
      public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
      }
    
      public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
      }
    
      public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
      }
```

Course class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
public class Course {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer courseId;

  @Column(nullable = false, length = 45)
  private String courseName;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id")
  private User user;


  public Integer getCourseId() {
    return courseId;
  }

  public void setCourseId(Integer courseId) {
    this.courseId = courseId;
  }

  public String getCourseName() {
    return courseName;
  }

  public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
    this.courseName = courseName;
  }
}
```

course_form.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xml:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="text-center"><h2>[[${pageTitle}]]</h2></div>

  <form th:action="@{/courses/save}" method="post" th:object="${course}"  style="max-width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{courseId}">
    <div class="border border-secondary rounded p-3">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Course name</label>
        <div class="col col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" th:field="*{courseName}" class="form-group" required minlength="5"
                 maxlength="45">
          <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" class="form-group" required minlength="5"
                 maxlength="45">
        </div>


          <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Teacher</label>
          <div class="col col-sm-8">
            <select  class="col col-sm-8">
              <th:block  th:each="user :${listUsers}">
                <option value="[[${user.id}]]">[[${user.id}]]</option>
              </th:block>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>


      <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-2">
          Save
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary m-2" onclick="cancelForm()">
          Cancel
        </button>
      </div>


    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Error message:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/course_form.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/course_form.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1397)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "course_form" - line 28, col 30)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "course_form" - line 28, col 30)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:260)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:256)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:169)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:104)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlVoidElement.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlVoidElement.java:92)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:297)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:402)
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseOpenElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:159)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:710)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'course' of bean class [by.dratsevich.mycrud.courses.Course]: Bean property 'course' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getNestedPropertyAccessor(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:843)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyAccessorForPropertyPath(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:820)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:615)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:104)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:228)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    ... 66 more
```

Comment: Include _the complete error message_, most especially the final `Caused by:`.

Comment: `th:field="*{id}"` Your `Course` class does not have a `id` property, its `courseId`. However the stacktrace mentions: `Invalid property 'course' of bean class [by.dratsevich.mycrud.courses.Course]:...` So it implies that you are trying to access a field/property named `course` from your `Course` class...Are you sure that the posted html code reflects to the one of the stacktrace?

Comment: @pleft yes, im shure. I want to make connection with tables in my DB. I'm using spring annotation 
`@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private User user;`
And in my table Course i have new column id

Comment: @andrewJames i tried to use `<option value="${user.id}">[[${user.id}]]</option>` in my code but i still have a problem. And problem is in this line `<input type="text" th:field="*{id}" class="form-group" required minlength="5"
                 maxlength="45">`
I have column `id` in my table Course, but it doesnt work

Comment: Side note: Using `value="[[${user.id}]]"` will probably not give you what you want. It will render literally to `value="[[${user.id}]]"`. You should use `th:value="${user.id}"`. Not a solution - just an observation.

Comment: Sorry - I deleted my first comment because I mis-read the code in the question. There is a different problem, as per my new comment - but it is not the cause of your error.